# How to save image url in database through carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, carrierwave

How to save the url of image in database instead of the image name by using carrierwave?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `image` as the field mounted in `User` model for carrierwave, just to get the url you could do

```
user = User.first
user.image.url
```

But if you definitely need an image url then you can add a new column `image_url` then you could add a `after_save` method in your model and update the field with the url.

```
# in user.rb
after_save do |user|
  user.update(image_url, user.image.url)
end
```